# Chat session between two clients of same web application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, client-server

I have a web application say for a school and It has 4 modules viz. for Management (school management), Student, Teachers and Parents. I need to build a module for letting any Parent chat to any Management Personnel (specific department) for any issue. Now, I need a direction or specific coding example, if possible, to get it done.

What I want is that all the Management Personnel who are logged in to be shown and If a parent wish to chat with a Management Personnel, he/she may enter the department and any one amongst the department who is available at that time in queue can chat. Also, how to start and continue until end with chat is a issue.

Since, I haven't done anything like this before, please explain in the simplest of the way of you can.

Comment: The scope of a potential answer to this question is huge and would likely require someone to do it for you in order for the answer to be satisfactory.  Have you written any code for this?  How would you approach it?  What things like this have you done before?

Comment: What does a chat consist of? Basically putting messages somewhere and then reading them from there.  Hmmmm...I think there's a technology that does basically nothing but that...what was that called again?

Comment: Dear xDaevax, As stated I haven't written any code for this and my approach may be: I will put the Management Personnel in Group chat as soon as he login and set him available for chat. Once a paret apply for chat he/she will have to choose department and when its doe, all the available Management Personnel who are available will be checked for their departments and one of amongst them will be choose to open a chat session.

Comment: This old question is unfortunately far too broad, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a lots of logic here.
First **Normalize** database properly, then proceed for functionality